# Determine if html select contains a value in any of its child options

Tags: jquery

Given a select

```
<select id="Myselect">
<option value="-1">Please Select<option>
<option value="1">Selection 1<option>
<option value="2">Selection 2<option>
</select>
```

What the best way to determine if there is an option of value X in the select with JQuery?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do this using a selector and [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/), like this:

```
var exists = $("#mySelect option[value='-1']").length !== 0;
```

Or as a function:

```
function optionExists(val) {
  return $("#mySelect option[value='" + val + "']").length !== 0;
}
```

If it's not numbers and you may have `'` in there for example (screwing the selector), you can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
function optionExists(val) {
  return $("#mySelect option").filter(function() {
           return this.value === val;
         }).length !== 0;
}
```

Comment: why not using `var exists = $("#mySelect option[value='-1']") != undefined`, getting the objects to access directly

Comment: @jAndy - Because it's not undefined :) It's a jQuery object containing 0 DOM elements, so `.length === 0` :) Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2drxN/

Comment: @jAndy - You're trying to access the first element in an array that has no elements so yes *that* will be undefined :)  The normal `$("anything")` will never be undefined though, it'll just have no elements to execute the rest of the chain on.

Comment: @Nick: I'm not sure if `var exists = $("#mySelect option[value='-1']")[0]` would bring any benefit. If something is found, you'll have the DOMelement in `exists` fine, but you still would have to wrap it into a jQuery object afterwards. So maybe a stupid approach :)

Answer (score 6):

The [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector should work, something like this:

```
var exists = $("#Myselect:has(option[value='X'])").length > 0;
```

This is far from the only way, but an easy to understand approach.
You could also do somethi.g like [this for an .Exists()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery) function since `.length > 0` is sometimes not clear to mean it does exist.

Comment: `.length > 0` means the selector *found* something, meaning it exists ..so can you explain your last statement? I'm not following there.  Also you need a closing `]` in there...but I wouldn't go this way, this is just extra work inside Sizzle.